# Rails ActiveRecord not saving updates - but not raising any errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

Im trying to update a record in `sqlserver` using the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem when i try and save the record in the console it shows as if its updated fine but when i check the database nothing was updated.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

 before_validation :make_CustomerID

 self.primary_key = :CustomerID
 self.table_name = "CoCustomers"

 def make_CustomerID
  self.CustomerID = Customer.all.last.CustomerID + 1
 end

end
```

in the rails console

```
c = Customer.find(1)
c.CustomerName
=> "ABC Co."
c.CustomerName = "XYZ Co."
=> "XYZ Co."
c.save

SQL (42.8ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  Customer Load (49.9ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [CoCustomers].* FROM [CoCustomers]'
   (45.3ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE [CoCustomers] SET [CustomerName] = N''XYZ Co.'', [LastUpdate] = ''2014-01-10T16:37:52.488'' WHERE [CoCustomers].[CustomerID] = 3; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRows'
SQL (45.6ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
=> true 
c.CustomerName
=> "XYZ Co."
c = Customerfind(1)
c.CustomerName
=> "ABC Co."
```

in shows as if its updating but nothing is actually happening as you can see.

additionally i have set my `application.rb` file to

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

I am using `rails 3.2.16` with the `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.12`

any help would be great, thanks

Comment: `Customerfind(1)` vs `Customer.find(1)`? Is this a typo in SO only?

Comment: Why is that `update` statement executed on `CustomerID = 3`?

Comment: no it is retrieving the wrong ID

Comment: I added the on: :create to the before_validation hook and that took care of the problem

Comment: @AbM that was a typo - but the issue was already resolved

Comment: @vee that was the issue as D.Lovell pointed out in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no need of the make_customerID method hooked before_validation.  Rails will take care of generating the id for you.

Note the id in the SQL update statement.  It is three.  You are retrieving id one.

The way your Customer model is written, it will update the id on every validation.  Delete the before_validation hook (and the method).  That ought to fix it for you.

Comment: I added the on: :create to the before_validation hook and that took care of the problem

Comment: the column is not an auto_increment as its not a db generated by a rails migration rather an existing sqlserver db that i am trying to retrofit for rails